# Rails form_for password_field return type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, crypt

I have a simple signup form:

```
<h1>Signup as a new user</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

That redirects to the create method of the UsersController:

```
def create
  password  = params[:password].crypt("$1$}")
  @user = User.new(:username => params[:username], :password => password)
  @user.save
  flash[:message] = "User #{User.username} created!"
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

But this throws an error `undefined method crypt' for nil:NilClass`. Why would the password be Nil? I checked the HTML params and got this:

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aAcaURTLKfwmXULEUzLX36tZAKER/kMxKKOROOXgoU8=", "user"=>{"username"=>"Chris", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save"}`

Does `"[FILTERED}"` mean it isn't a string? How can I access it from `params`?

Comment: `"[FILTERED]"` means that the specific parameter has been removed from the log because it is sensitive information.  Depending on your version of Rails, any field called 'password' is automatically filtered.  See this page for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameter-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not nil, it just exists inside of :user, so try

```
params[:user][:password].crypt("$1$")
```

In fact all of your params work here is incorrect, all the fields are scoped by :user, this is one of the things that form_for does for you automatically.

So to get the username, you'd want to say `params[:user][:username]`.